Trying to understand Ch.2.1 "2.1. Monads and their algebras" of "Categorical Deep Learning: An Algebraic Theory of Architectures"
I am trying to read article "Categorical Deep Learning: An Algebraic Theory of Architectures" https://arxiv.org/abs/2402.15332 and I am stuck with the Chapter 2.1 "2.1. Monads and their algebras".
As I understand, then category C is category of data-sets. E.g. photograph (resp. - its data-set of pixels) 1-1 of world-object 1 is one object of category C. Photograph m-n of world-object m is another object of category C.
Now I am very confused about the defining monad M on C by group G. I understand what the moand is: monad M maps each photogrpah m-n into another photograph m'-n' (or at least m-n' - different photograph of the same world-object m). That is fine. But if we take group and trying to make monad from it, then we should somehow get |G| monads (|| being the cardinality of the group), because each group element g should induce different m-n to m'-n' mapping and hence - different monad!
But the authors somehow say, that the group G defines just one monda? How it be so? How can we apply entire group to one photograph and get just one photograph as a result?
And things are becoming more confused if we go to the algebra M(A)->A. A (according to my interpretation) is the photograph. I we apply M, how can we get the same photograph A? And, all the previously said remains - application M(A) should yield the mass of photographs.
I see one very, very special case, when my problems collapse and this is the case, when photograph A is invariant against all transformation of the group G (which defines monad M). Yes, in this very, very special case the monad A yields just one single photograph to each input photograph and this photograph is the same for all the elements of G that define M. But this special case is so special, that it had to be mentioned explicitly? And the article speaks about such invariances, then the this framework is very narrow indeed.
Pls, can someone clarify all those notions? I know category theory well enough, but I can not see how these definitions can be applied in a manner as they are reading them from the article.
